# Creating a good search solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app where users have a role,a username,faculty and so on.When I'm looking for a list of users by their role or faculty or anything they have in common I can call (among others possible)

```
      @users = User.find_by_role(params[:role]) #or
      @users = User.find_by_shift(params[:shift])
```

So it keeps the system

```
      Class.find_by_property
```

So the question is: What if at different points users lists should be generated based on different properties.I mean: I'm passing from different links

1. params[:role] or
2. params[:faculty] or
3. params[:department]

to my list action in my users controller.As I see it all has to be in that action,but which parameter should the search be made by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try https://github.com/ernie/meta_search if you're on Rails 3

Comment: I guess I was looking for a dynamic way of doing it.I mean I just found a guy that does http://blog.teksol.info/2005/10/31/building-the-sql-where-clause-dynamically-in-rails But this will do it too :)